# How to store output looped elements of an array in another array

Tags: java

I have edited a java method for finding peaks by comparing its neighboring elements. But I have a problem in storing the values in the output array...

Here is the method that is edited, commented is my problem

```
public static int[] peakInArray(int[] arr2){
    int i;
    int lenghtInput = arr2.length;
    int[] peaks = new int[lenghtInput];
    for (i = 1; i<arr2.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr2[i] > arr2[i - 1] && arr2[i] > arr2[i + 1]);
       // PROBLEM: store arr2[i] in peaks
        peaks[i] = arr2[i];
    }
    return peaks;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing actually

Comment: Is there a compilation/runtime error?  If so, please paste it.  Is something else going wrong?  Telling us you have a "problem" is really vague.

Comment: if the condition is satisfy you want to store that value in another array right still you are using same index i for peaks !!

Comment: The problem is that you've used `if(...);` the `;` at the end makes this `if` statement useless.

Comment: OP, if your issue is that peaks is storing **everything** from arr2, then what @Titus eluded to (replace `;` with `{}`, like your `for` loop) is likely the solution.  If you notice other problems, please post more detailed info about what the actual problem is.

Comment: There is no error... The problem is that when i try to enter the array [1,2,3,4,3,6,7,6,5], I'm expecting to have an output of [4,7] but the output is [0,2,3,4,3,6,7,6,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all who helped me in my problem, thanks!
I've figured it out with your help and with some researches.

Here is the final method...

```
public static int[] peakInArray(int[] arr2){

    int lengthInput = arr2.length;
    int[] peaks = new int[lengthInput];
    int peakIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i<lengthInput - 1; i ++) {
        if (arr2[i] > arr2[i - 1] && arr2[i] > arr2[i + 1]) {
            //Store arr2[i] in peaks
            peaks[peakIndex] = arr2[i];
            peakIndex++;
        }
    }
 return peaks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone already said, your `if` statement shouldn't be working the way you have it. It needs to be:

```
if(yourComparison){
   peaks[i] = arr2[i];
}
```

Also, if you want your result to only be as big as it needs to be, you need to use an ArrayList. There's an example at the bottom of this page:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm